# My Websphere is starting and stopping and then starting automatically

Tags: java, websphere

I am using RSA as IDE and deploy the application in Websphere application server 6.1

I have the below logs where the application seems to have started and then somehow stops and starts deploying or publishing again.

Is there anything I can do in the configurations for preventing this?

```
[8/1/12 11:43:40:158 IST] 0000001a ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml'
[8/1/12 11:43:40:158 IST] 0000001a ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml'
[8/1/12 11:43:40:345 IST] 0000001a ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [GlobalDorfEAR] [/dorf] [action]: Initialization successful.
[8/1/12 11:43:40:345 IST] 0000001a VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module GlobalDorf has been bound to default_host[*:11000,*:80,*:11002,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].
[8/1/12 11:43:40:361 IST] 0000001a ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: GlobalDorfEAR
[8/1/12 11:43:40:813 IST] 00000019 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: isclite.
[8/1/12 11:43:45:456 IST] 00000019 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [EventInitializer]: Initialization successful.
[8/1/12 11:43:45:488 IST] 00000019 VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module isclite has been bound to admin_host[*:11001,*:11003].
[8/1/12 11:43:45:519 IST] 00000019 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: adminconsole redirector.
[8/1/12 11:43:45:550 IST] 00000019 VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module adminconsole redirector has been bound to admin_host[*:11001,*:11003].
[8/1/12 11:43:45:566 IST] 00000019 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: EHS3.01.
[8/1/12 11:43:45:924 IST] 00000019 VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module EHS3.01 has been bound to admin_host[*:11001,*:11003].
[8/1/12 11:43:46:938 IST] 00000019 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Integrated Solutions Console.
[8/1/12 11:43:47:297 IST] 00000019 VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module Integrated Solutions Console has been bound to admin_host[*:11001,*:11003].
[8/1/12 11:43:48:046 IST] 00000019 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: WIM.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:077 IST] 00000019 VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module WIM has been bound to admin_host[*:11001,*:11003].
[8/1/12 11:43:48:311 IST] 00000019 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: WebSphere Application Server.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:342 IST] 00000019 VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module WebSphere Application Server has been bound to admin_host[*:11001,*:11003].
**[8/1/12 11:43:48:342 IST] 00000019 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: isclite
[8/1/12 11:43:48:498 IST] 0000000a TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_1 is listening on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 11001. 
[8/1/12 11:43:48:498 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundAdmin.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:529 IST] 0000000a TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_2 is listening on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 11000. 
[8/1/12 11:43:48:561 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefault.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:561 IST] 0000000a TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_3 is listening on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 11003. 
[8/1/12 11:43:48:561 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundAdminSecure.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:561 IST] 0000000a TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_4 is listening on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 11002. 
[8/1/12 11:43:48:576 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundDefaultSecure.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:592 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain1.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:592 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain2.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:592 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain3.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:592 IST] 0000000a WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain SOAPAcceptorChain4.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:623 IST] 0000001a SchedulerServ I   SCHD0077I: The Scheduler Service is starting the Schedulers.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:623 IST] 0000001a SchedulerServ I   SCHD0078I: The Scheduler Service has completed starting the Schedulers.
[8/1/12 11:43:48:717 IST] 0000000a RMIConnectorC A   ADMC0026I: The RMI Connector is available at port 2809
[8/1/12 11:43:49:185 IST] 0000000c WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is false.
[8/1/12 11:43:49:840 IST] 0000000a WsServerImpl  A   WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business
[8/1/12 11:43:54:263 IST] 00000029 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.43.54_0.txt
[8/1/12 11:43:54:325 IST] 00000029 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.43.54_0.txt
[8/1/12 11:44:15:425 IST] 00000029 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.44.15_0.txt
[8/1/12 11:44:15:425 IST] 00000029 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.44.15_0.txt
[8/1/12 11:44:28:007 IST] 00000029 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1010I: An attempt is made to stop the GlobalDorfEAR application. (User ID = customRealm/wasadm01)
[8/1/12 11:44:28:022 IST] 00000029 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: GlobalDorfEAR
[8/1/12 11:44:28:038 IST] 00000029 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0253I: [GlobalDorfEAR] [/dorf] [MenuInitServlet]: Destroy successful.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:069 IST] 00000029 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0253I: [GlobalDorfEAR] [/dorf] [action]: Destroy successful.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:132 IST] 00000029 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0041I: Stopping EJB jar: GlobalDorfEJB.jar
[8/1/12 11:44:28:132 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfCopyTimesheetActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#CopyTimesheetMessageProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:194 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfSowUploadActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#SowUploadMessageProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:210 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfSidReleaseActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#SidReleaseMessageProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:225 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfMissingTimesheetActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#MissingTimesheetProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:225 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfPaymentUploadActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#PaymentUploadProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:225 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfCopyPersonsActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#CopyPersonsProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:241 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfBillingActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#BillingMessageProcessBean is deactivated.
[8/1/12 11:44:28:256 IST] 00000029 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0059I: EJB jar stopped: GlobalDorfEJB.jar
[8/1/12 11:44:28:256 IST] 00000029 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: GlobalDorfEAR
[8/1/12 11:44:28:740 IST] 00000029 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the GlobalDorfEAR application. (User ID = customRealm/wasadm01)
[8/1/12 11:44:28:974 IST] 00000029 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: GlobalDorfEAR**
[8/1/12 11:44:28:974 IST] 00000029 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: GlobalDorfEAR  Application build level: Unknown
[8/1/12 11:44:29:114 IST] 00000029 SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0017I: Configuration reload is starting for bus server1_Bus.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:177 IST] 00000029 SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0018I: Configuration reload is complete for bus server1_Bus.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:192 IST] 00000029 SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0019I: Configuration reload is starting for messaging engine server1Node.server1-server1_Bus.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:224 IST] 00000029 SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0020I: Configuration reload is complete for messaging engine server1Node.server1-server1_Bus.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:224 IST] 00000029 SibMessage    I   [:] CWSIS1569I: Messaging engine server1Node.server1-server1_Bus is using a file store.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:380 IST] 00000029 ResourceMgrIm I   WSVR0049I: Binding DefaultEJBTimerDataSource as jdbc/DefaultEJBTimerDataSource
[8/1/12 11:44:29:395 IST] 00000029 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: GlobalDorfEJB.jar
[8/1/12 11:44:29:614 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfSowUploadActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#SowUploadMessageProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:645 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfCopyTimesheetActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#CopyTimesheetMessageProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:676 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfBillingActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#BillingMessageProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:692 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfSidReleaseActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#SidReleaseMessageProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:692 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfMissingTimesheetActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#MissingTimesheetProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:707 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfCopyPersonsActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#CopyPersonsProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:723 IST] 00000029 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0523I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec eis/globaldorfPaymentUploadActivationSpec (com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jmsra.impl.JmsJcaActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application GlobalDorfEAR#GlobalDorfEJB.jar#PaymentUploadProcessBean is activated.
[8/1/12 11:44:29:848 IST] 00000029 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0057I: EJB jar started: GlobalDorfEJB.jar
[8/1/12 11:44:31:439 IST] 00000029 WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: GlobalDorf.
[8/1/12 11:44:31:517 IST] 00000029 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.44.31_0.txt
[8/1/12 11:44:31:548 IST] 00000029 ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.44.31_0.txt
[8/1/12 11:44:31:579 IST] 00000029 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld]: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource file:/C:/Global_dorf/srcRAD200805/GlobalDorFWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld
[8/1/12 11:44:31:579 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:579 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:579 IST] 00000029 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld]: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource file:/C:/Global_dorf/srcRAD200805/GlobalDorFWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld
[8/1/12 11:44:31:595 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:595 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:610 IST] 00000029 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld]: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource file:/C:/Global_dorf/srcRAD200805/GlobalDorFWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld
[8/1/12 11:44:31:626 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:642 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:642 IST] 00000029 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld]: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource file:/C:/Global_dorf/srcRAD200805/GlobalDorFWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld
[8/1/12 11:44:31:642 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:642 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:657 IST] 00000029 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld]: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource file:/C:/Global_dorf/srcRAD200805/GlobalDorFWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld
[8/1/12 11:44:31:657 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:657 IST] 00000029 jsp           W com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TagLibraryCache loadWebXmlMap jsp warning failed to load tld at [/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld]
[8/1/12 11:44:31:548 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.appmgmt.monitoring.SessionCounterMBean).
[8/1/12 11:44:31:548 IST] 00000029 SystemErr     R log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[8/1/12 11:44:31:922 IST] 00000029 CacheConfigur I com.ford.it.cache.internal.CacheConfigurationManager setDiskStoreConfiguration Cache Disk Store Path = C:/proj/server1/was/caches/server1
[8/1/12 11:44:31:985 IST] 00000029 CacheManager  I net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager addShutdownHookIfRequired The CacheManager shutdown hook is enabled because net.sf.ehcache.enableShutdownHook is set to true.
[8/1/12 11:44:32:063 IST] 00000029 CacheManager  I net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager addShutdownHookIfRequired The CacheManager shutdown hook is enabled because net.sf.ehcache.enableShutdownHook is set to true.
[8/1/12 11:44:32:156 IST] 00000029 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [GlobalDorfEAR] [/dorf] [MenuInitServlet]: Initialization successful.
[8/1/12 11:44:32:203 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O was.process.name is set to server1
[8/1/12 11:44:32:219 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O 655 [ORB.thread.pool : 0] INFO com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.InitServlet  - *** global dorF Initializer started
[8/1/12 11:44:32:266 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     702] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,250] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.InitServlet init: Logger initialized
[8/1/12 11:44:32:266 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     718] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,266] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.initializer.ConverterInitializer init: register Converters...
[8/1/12 11:44:32:297 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     749] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,297] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.initializer.ConverterInitializer init: register Converters...done
[8/1/12 11:44:32:297 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     749] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,297] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.initializer.ConfigFilesInitializer init: init app & env config
[8/1/12 11:44:32:297 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     749] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,297] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.initializer.ConfigFilesInitializer init: Load application and env config file: C:\Global_dorf\srcRAD200805\GlobalDorFWeb\WebContent/WEB-INF/properties/app-config-global-dorF.xml,environment.xml
[8/1/12 11:44:32:297 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     749] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,297] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.initializer.ConfigFilesInitializer init: init app & env & payment config... load appConfig
[8/1/12 11:44:32:344 IST] 00000029 SystemOut     O [     796] [2012-08-01 11:44:32,344] ORB.thread.pool : 0 [ INFO] com.ford.adsbo.globaldorf.utils.initializer.ConfigFilesInitializer init: init app & env & payment config... load envConfig
```

---

Below you can find the FFDC logs

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1      1     8/8/12 11:26:59:550 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1    241     8/8/12 11:28:00:096 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1    493     8/8/12 11:29:02:056 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1    745     8/8/12 11:30:03:970 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1    997     8/8/12 11:31:05:909 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1   1249     8/8/12 11:32:07:964 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1   1501     8/8/12 11:33:09:942 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1   1737     8/8/12 11:34:10:235 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1   1969     8/8/12 11:35:10:724 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
+    2      1     8/8/12 11:35:44:698 IST javax.servlet.ServletException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 172

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1      1     8/8/12 11:36:20:483 IST java.io.FileNotFoundException com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementBaseFactory 1867
     2   2137     8/8/12 11:35:58:161 IST javax.naming.NameNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.do_resolve_complete_info 1133
     3      1     8/8/12 11:35:44:698 IST javax.servlet.ServletException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 172
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
+    4      1     8/8/12 11:37:55:745 IST javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException com.ibm.ws.management.PlatformMBeanServer.registerMBean 523
+    5      1     8/8/12 11:40:09:213 IST java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTConnectionContext.finishConnection 64

---

THe below logs show the server to have been stopped.

C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_00000029_12.08.01_11.44.15_0.txt [8/1/12 11:44:28:007 IST] 00000029 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1010I: An attempt is made to stop the GlobalDorfEAR application. (User ID = customRealm/wasadm01) [8/1/12 11:44:28:022 IST] 00000029 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: GlobalDorfEAR [8/1/12 11:44:28:038 IST] 00000029 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0253I: [GlobalDorfEAR] [/dorf] [MenuInitServlet]: Destroy successful. [8/1/12 11:44:28:069 IST] 00000029 ServletWrappe I   SRVE0253I: [GlobalDorfEAR] [/dorf] [action]: Destroy successful. [8/1/12 11:44:28:132 IST] 00000029 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0041I: Stopping EJB jar: GlobalDorfEJB.jar

---

I am able to see that the server is up but the application is being stopped automatically and started.

[8/8/12 11:36:51:117 IST] 0000001f AdminHelper   A   ADMN1010I: An attempt is made to stop the GlobalDorfEAR application. (User ID = customRealm/wasadm01)
[8/8/12 11:36:51:133 IST] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: GlobalDorfEAR

Comment: Have you checked FFDC logs (C:\Users\asakthi1\WAS-profiles\6.1\server1\logs\ffdc\server1_*.txt) ?

Comment: Your snippet shows two separate applications being started (GlobalDorfEAR and isclite), but I don't see any messages about it being stopped.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Auto publish turned on? This could result in application being published everytime something changes. Auto publish coupled with "build automatically" can be a possible reason.

As mentioned by Konstantin, what do the FFDC logs say?

Also notice this line in your logs
*ADMN1010I: An attempt is made to stop the GlobalDorfEAR application. (User ID = customRealm/wasadm01)*.

It states clearly that a request is made to stop this application by **wasadm01**. I am guessing that this is the userid that is specified in your RSA to connect to the WAS Server.